# Grep-ing for a line beginning with a Maven version number

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep a file for a line that begins with a version number of the form:

> X.Y.Z

where X, Y and Z are numbers between 0 and infinity.

As an example say the the line of interest begins `20.2.3`

The following will return a result if the first character of the line is a digit:

`grep ^[0-9]`

The result is:

> **2**0.2.3`

where the bold indicates what grep has 'matched on'.
However this will also match lines beginning `4000-43` which I do not want.

So in my regex naivety I tried the following grep:

> grep ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]

thinking this would match any line beginning with **any** number followed by two other numbers separated by decimal-points. But it does not.

If I try:

> grep ^[0-9]+

it doesn't match anything at all.

How do I modify my regex to match the number format I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `+` (one or more) quantifier should be escaped with `\` when using in BRE (basic regular expressions) mode (default mode):

```
grep '^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]' <<<"20.2.3"
20.2.3
```

---

Otherwise, to make it work - use `-E` option to enable ERE (extended regular expressions) mode:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]' <<<"20.2.3"
20.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a pretty good one, just add `\` before the `+`.

```
grep "^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]" <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want lines starting with numbers and periods but not starting with a period (`-o` to weed out anything following the version number):

```
$ echo 20.2.3 foo |  
  grep -o ^[^.][0-9.]\\+
20.2.3
```